# How to write a Python class with different methods in different cases?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

Suppose we have two classes A and B

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       pass 
   def print_abc(self):
       print('abc')

class B:
   def __init__(self):
       pass 
   def print_def(self):
       print('def')
```

We use class A in the case when we want to work with storageA, and class B when we want to work with storageB. Now, is there a way to write one class, named C, which uses method print_abc if storageA is in question and print_def if storageB is in question? In some sense hypothetical something like this:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, storage):
        self.storage = storage
    
    @storage=storageA
    def print_abc(self):
        print('abc')
    @storage=storageB
    def print_def(self):
        print('def')
```

Is something like this possible and how?

Comment: That seems like anti-OOP - the point of having classes to wrap the different types of storage would be so that the consumers *don't* have to know the difference.

Comment: Well, my problem is that I want to write DataHandler class that manages S3 and Glacier, but with method create_bucket for S3 and create_vault for Glacier.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the public interface should be e.g. `create_store`, the fact that it's a vault for S3 and a bucket for Glacier would then be abstracted.

Comment: Thnx. That makes sense